# IntelliJ IDEA - CodenameOne - CEF path not found after AndroidStudio installation/JDK change?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, codenameone, chromium-embedded, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am having this issue on a Windows10 system.

I changed JDK to OpenJDK 1.8 to be able to send the Android build.

On the device the app is working although I have not tested the CEF Browser part for now.

On the simulator the app is executed, but blocked after the exception (a dialog is displayed).

Also if I revert to Oracle JDK11 the issue persists.

The app was regularly working. I also installed AndroidStudio on my system, maybe it has messed up with PATHs.

How can I fix this now?

(see log below)

Thanks

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-203.7148.57, built on January 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 978M
Cores: 4
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.codename1.plugin.intellij, org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\java.exe" -Xms128m -Xmx1011m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=\"\" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57718:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\myappcp\out\production\myappcp;C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\myappcp\src;C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\myappcp\lib\CodenameOne.jar;C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\myappcp\JavaSE.jar;native\internal_tmp;lib\impl\cls com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.myappcp.app.myapp
Adding CEF to classpath
Retina Scale: 1.0
[EDT] 0:0:4,330 - Codename One revisions: 7dd4e7d08b3442d90959477ee52a5ae8c4361b29

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create CEF browser
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:130)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:98)
    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent$9.run(BrowserComponent.java:557)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1338)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1280)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1162)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcef in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.cef.CefApp.<init>(CefApp.java:149)
    at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:221)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.BrowserPanel.<init>(BrowserPanel.java:204)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent$3.<init>(CEFBrowserComponent.java:249)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:248)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:199)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:196)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:136)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$2.run(JavaCEFSEPort.java:120)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[EDT] 0:0:4,409 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Failed to create CEF browser
[EDT] 0:0:6,490 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Failed to create CEF browser
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create CEF browser
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:130)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:98)
    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent$9.run(BrowserComponent.java:557)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1338)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1280)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1453)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1492)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.showModal(Form.java:2552)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showModal(Dialog.java:1139)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:583)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPackedImpl(Dialog.java:1452)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPacked(Dialog.java:1368)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showImpl(Dialog.java:1095)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1073)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1028)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:794)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:747)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:712)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:653)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:808)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1175)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcef in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.cef.CefApp.<init>(CefApp.java:149)
    at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:221)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.BrowserPanel.<init>(BrowserPanel.java:204)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent$3.<init>(CEFBrowserComponent.java:249)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:248)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:199)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:196)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:136)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$2.run(JavaCEFSEPort.java:120)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create CEF browser
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:130)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:98)
    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent$9.run(BrowserComponent.java:557)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1338)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1280)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1453)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1492)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.showModal(Form.java:2552)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showModal(Dialog.java:1139)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:583)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPackedImpl(Dialog.java:1452)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPacked(Dialog.java:1368)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showImpl(Dialog.java:1095)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1073)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1028)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:794)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:747)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:712)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:653)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:808)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1175)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcef in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.cef.CefApp.<init>(CefApp.java:149)
    at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:221)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.BrowserPanel.<init>(BrowserPanel.java:204)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent$3.<init>(CEFBrowserComponent.java:249)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:248)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:199)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:196)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:136)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$2.run(JavaCEFSEPort.java:120)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I reset the IDE and now I think the problem is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcef in java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin, C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\, C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem, C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\, C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\, C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL, C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT, C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL, C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT, C:\Program Files\dotnet\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\, C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps, ., C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\bin, ., C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin, C:\Users\user\.dotnet\tools, C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Box\Box Edit\, .]
```

Comment: JCEF is available in the JetBrains Runtime bundled with IntelliJ IDEA and not available in JDK 1.8 you are using. If your app uses JCEF, you need to run it using the same runtime as the IDE itself is running under (under jbr subdirectory of the IDE home directory).

Comment: @CrazyCoder My project seems to be  messed up. JDK paths are overwritten even if I change them. Please can you tell me each occurrence I have to set and what to set?

Comment: Project Structure | Project | SDK. Run Configuration | JRE.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Please check the edited post, I appended some information. I think the problem is about paths in the environment variable. Thanks

Comment: JDK doesn't have JCEF out of the box, only JetBrains Runtime does.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I would like to fix this problem. I see that CEF is in .codenameone folder.

Comment: You can add CEF directory to PATH or to -Djava.library.path VM option.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I put the path in the VM option you say, in the custom VM Option file, but now I get: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcef in java.library.path: [C:\Users\user\.codenameone\cef]  (also with [C:\Users\user\.codenameone\cef\lib\win64)

Comment: How does the VM Option look like? Do you use 64-bit JVM?

Comment: It shouldn't need an additional path. Just use Update project from Codename One Preferences which should install everything that's needed and update CEF with the current version. You can delete the CEF files you have right now and do an update, the system should fetch the right files for you.

Comment: @Shai Almog The update did not automatically restore the cef folder. So I restored it manually but I have the same error. Maybe I have to uninstall/reinstall IDEA and restart a fresh project import.

Comment: Did you run the update twice? What are the versions in the project versions file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `java.library.path` has been changed or **JCEF** binaries are located elsewhere.

So, first you need to find out where **JCEF binary distribution** is. Usually this folder contains files:

- libcef.dll
- libEGL.dll,
- libGLESv2.dll
- libcef.dll
- libjcef.dll
- jcef_helper.exe

or *.so extension if you use unix base OS.

*If you don't have binary distribution of **JCEF** you can build it from sources using this [link](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding). I want to warn you this is not easy journey. In the last step(packaging) you'll get **binary_distrib** directory*

Second, your system already has configured the paths where it looking for the jcef binaries. You can see it in Exception details:

> java.library.path: [**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin**, **C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin**, ...

Or you can verify it by adding VM option to IDEA and run application again:

```
Edit Configurations -> Modify options -> Tick Add VM options -> In appeared field put -XshowSettings:properties
```

Third, You need to put **JCEF binaries** to one of these `java.library.path`

Hope this advice helps you